# Excel Power Query to only show unhidden rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

i have an excel workbook with 3 worksheets. each of the worksheet contains hidden and unhidden rows. i’ve managed to combine all 3 worksheets into one single worksheet via power query. however, the worksheet generated shows all the hidden and unhidden rows. is there anyways i could just generate the worksheet with just the unhidden rows?

i’ve read about using a helping column and applying a filter on it but i am unsure of how to do that as well. any new suggestions/walkthrough is greatly appreciated

Comment: Power Query itself can't detect if an Excel worksheet row is hidden or not. A simple additional column within the worksheet to flag whether the row is hidden will work, which can then be used as a filter within Power Query. Are the 'hidden' rows in your case rows which have been manually hidden, or did you mean that they are rows which are not part of the current filters applied?

Comment: @JosWoolley the rows are hidden due to checkboxes (macros), will this affect anything?

Comment: So your helper column would comprise a formula which looks at a column which contains non-blank entries, of the form `=SUBTOTAL(103,A1)`, which will return a 1 if the row comprising that cell is unhidden and a 0 otherwise.

Comment: @JosWoolley so what would the formula be?

Comment: The one that I just gave you, amending `A1` to the first cell in your chosen column, then copying down to the last row containing data. As I said, this will return a 0 or 1, depending on whether that row is hidden or not.

Comment: @JosWoolley apologies for the lack of knowledge here as it’s super new to me, but i suppose amending means putting a filter in the header in A1 with the above formula?

Comment: No, let's assume your data is in `A1:H1000`, with headers in row 1. You need to pick a column within that table which you can guarantee will never have any blanks. Let's say that column A satisfies that criterion. You then go to the first column just to the right of your current data; in this case that will be column I. You then put the formula `=SUBTOTAL(103,A2)` in cell `I2` and copy down to cell `I1000`. The reason the formula is referencing `A2`: the '2' comes from the fact that we are are in row 2; the 'A' comes from the fact that that was the column we decided would never contain blanks.

Comment: @JosWoolley hi, it worked wonders but why is it 103 and is there a way for it to be refreshed dynamically? instead of power querying it every single time?

Comment: What do you mean by 'refresh dynamically'? All queries must be refreshed when changes to the worksheet(s) concerned are made. You can have queries refresh via VBA if you want, for example via a worksheet change event, though you should probably start a new question for this.

Comment: @JosWoolley alright thank you! but may i still know what’s the significance of 103 in the formula?

Comment: Oh, for that you don't need Stack Overflow - you can find out the significance of that parameter in the official documentation for that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Power Query.

You can unzip the XLSX file to XML tables, and examine the row attributes - then get the sheet data, and merge the hidden attribute with the row number.

Pass this function the file name (including path) and sheet name, and it will return the sheet contents, with an added "Row hidden" column:

```
//fnGetRowHiddenStatus
(MyFileName as text, MySheetName as text) =>
let
    fnUnzip = (ZIPFile, Position, FileToExtract, DataSoFar) => 
    let 
      MyBinaryFormat = try BinaryFormat.Record([DataToSkip=BinaryFormat.Binary(Position), 
              MiscHeader=BinaryFormat.Binary(18), 
              FileSize=BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger32, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
              UnCompressedFileSize=BinaryFormat.Binary(4),
              FileNameLen=BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger16, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
              ExtrasLen=BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger16, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
              TheRest=BinaryFormat.Binary()]) otherwise null,
      MyCompressedFileSize = try MyBinaryFormat(ZIPFile)[FileSize]+1 otherwise null,
      MyFileNameLen = try MyBinaryFormat(ZIPFile)[FileNameLen] otherwise null,
      MyExtrasLen = try MyBinaryFormat(ZIPFile)[ExtrasLen] otherwise null,
      MyBinaryFormat2 = try BinaryFormat.Record([DataToSkip=BinaryFormat.Binary(Position), Header=BinaryFormat.Binary(30), Filename=BinaryFormat.Text(MyFileNameLen), Extras=BinaryFormat.Binary(MyExtrasLen), Data=BinaryFormat.Binary(MyCompressedFileSize), TheRest=BinaryFormat.Binary()]) otherwise null,
      MyFileName = try MyBinaryFormat2(ZIPFile)[Filename] otherwise null,
      GetDataToDecompress = try MyBinaryFormat2(ZIPFile)[Data] otherwise null,
      DecompressData = try Binary.Decompress(GetDataToDecompress, Compression.Deflate) otherwise null,
      NewPosition = try Position + 30 + MyFileNameLen + MyExtrasLen + MyCompressedFileSize - 1 otherwise null,
      AsATable = Table.FromRecords({[Filename = MyFileName, Content=DecompressData]}),
      #"Appended Query" = if DecompressData = null then DataSoFar else if (MyFileName = FileToExtract) then AsATable else
        if (FileToExtract = "") and Position <> 0 then Table.Combine({DataSoFar, AsATable})
        else AsATable    
    in
      if  (MyFileName = FileToExtract) or (#"Appended Query" = DataSoFar) then
        #"Appended Query"
      else 
        @fnUnzip(ZIPFile, NewPosition, FileToExtract, #"Appended Query"),
    Unzipped = fnUnzip(File.Contents(MyFileName), 0, "", null),
    WorkbookXML = Xml.Tables(Table.SelectRows(Unzipped, each Text.Contains([Filename],"xl/workbook"))[Content]{0}),
    WorkbookData = Table.SelectRows(WorkbookXML, each [Name] = "sheets"){0}[Table]{0}[Table],
    SheetIDs = Table.ExpandTableColumn(WorkbookData, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships", {"Attribute:id"}, {"Attribute:id"}),
    SheetID = Text.Replace(Table.SelectRows(SheetIDs, each ([#"Attribute:name"] = MySheetName))[#"Attribute:id"]{0},"rId","sheet"),
    SheetXML = Xml.Tables(Table.SelectRows(Unzipped, each Text.Contains([Filename], "worksheets/" & SheetID))[Content]{0}),
    SheetData = Table.SelectRows(SheetXML, each [Name]="sheetData"){0}[Table]{0}[Table],
    Renamed = Table.RenameColumns(SheetData,{{"Attribute:r", "Row"}}),
    #"Row Data" = Table.SelectColumns(Renamed,{"Row", "Attribute:hidden"}, MissingField.Ignore),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Row Data",{{"Row", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Row Status" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Hidden", each try if [#"Attribute:hidden"] = "1" then true else false otherwise false, type logical),
    Workbook = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(MyFileName)),
    Worksheet = Table.SelectRows(Workbook, each ([Name] = MySheetName))[Data]{0},
    #"Added Row" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Worksheet, "Row", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Merged Row Status" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Row", {"Row"}, #"Row Status", {"Row"}, "Row Status", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Row Status" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Row Status", "Row Status", {"Hidden"}, {"Row hidden"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Row Status",{"Row"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Example:

```
let
    Source = fnGetRowHiddenStatus("C:\Temp\rowhide.xlsx", "Sheet1")
in
    Source
```